# How to create percentage stacked bar chart in plotly?

Tags: pandas, plotly

I have this code but want to create a stacked % bar chart. How would I do that?

```
fig = px.bar(df, x='date', y=['var1','var2','var3', 'var4'],barmode='stack')
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: At this time, there is no function that automatically handles this, so it seems that the only way is to calculate the component ratios on a time-series basis and graph the results. Please refer to [this SO response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46419180/pandas-normalize-within-the-group). and [Plotly Community](https://community.plotly.com/t/percent-stacked-bar-chart/60741)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should make a new column that calculate `%` of each `var` and then use it to deploy chart. Please refer my below code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime as dt
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': ['2022-01-07','2022-02-07','2022-03-07','2022-04-07','2022-05-07','2022-06-07','2022-07-07','2022-08-07'],
    'var1': [5,7,2,4,6,8,10,9],
    'var2': [6,7,8,5,2,6,3,1],
    'var3':[8,5,6,2,8,3,5,4],
    'var4':[7,9,7,5,3,4,2,1]})

df_melt = df.melt(id_vars=['date'],var_name='var',value_name='Amount',value_vars=df.columns[1:],ignore_index=True)

df_melt['%'] = 100 * df_melt['Amount'] / df_melt.groupby('date')['Amount'].transform('sum')

fig = px.bar(df_melt, x="date", y="%",color='var',
        title="Bar Plot", 
        template="plotly_white")   
fig.update_layout(barmode="relative")
fig.update_layout(plot_bgcolor='white')
fig.update_yaxes(showline=False,showgrid=False)
fig.update_xaxes(showline=False,showgrid=False)
fig.show()
```

And here is the Output:
[image]